# Goto in Sequence Diagram?

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

How can I show goto statements in Sequence Diagrams.

For example in the diagram below, once "sleep till hold period" is expired I want to take control back to the "is_item_inventory_onhold_state(item_id)" statement. How can I show this is a diagram?

[image]

I am using https://sequencediagram.org/ to create these diagrams.

Code written to generate the diagram above:

```
title Item Executor

loop  for each item in a list 
Client->ItemExecutor: execute(item)

ItemExecutor -> ItemStateService:is_item_inventory_onhold_state(item_id)

alt True - Item state is on hold
ItemStateService -->ItemExecutor: True
ItemExecutor ->ItemExecutor: sleep till hold period 

goto  ItemExecutor -> ItemStateService:is_item_inventory_onhold_state(item_id)

else False - Item is not in Held State
ItemStateService -->ItemExecutor:False
ItemExecutor ->ItemExecutor: do_something()

end

ItemExecutor ->Client : Acknowledge
end
```

Comment: Where's your goto statement in the code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Goto is not supported in sequence diagrams (for good reasons). Use a combination of a `loop` and a `break` operator instead. See this diagram:
[image]
[sequencediagram.org/Item Executor](https://sequencediagram.org/index.html#initialData=C4S2BsFMAIElkgW2gUQB6QMYFdgHsAnAKAAcBDA0TEcgO2GgGFwRJ7SKqaz7oAiVgC54SdFlyE+0MgGc4CRGJz5i5SiGp0GAhAWG6yKqbOhhIqzhu68++pAGVghyPfMA3DZGNyRiR89cCD0xIImZWegBaAD5wtmBBM0QZGLMCQ0IACgBKMJZ4yJi4+kTdAF4icDw8ElNdADoAC1kAOUg0YBzoPIjgVN1BWnbO3KIyTFA3ZzrzIjTC2PySpLKhjpyiABNIccnptJ6C6N8lCT1odvEETKTRqpqiE4xlQmgY+QcnBEDgyESZAD6SSBtDc8UIAE8AXhaI08OBNgCZF9IDcFPUQJtRkQasBHgp-N93J4Fk8roRBIJgARsKEyS8CG9jgpTipBNAZFBICRMnCEdASOYQHgsd02JsiAAjAg7ADW3V8hJcxJCpJZzzOlIAZmRwDJQuKiIb6WcmSa2dBNngkXhEJBgI0QLQAOZopC5c2vBbFBJG2ibaBAA)

[sequencediagram.org/Item Executor (with Execution Specifications)](https://sequencediagram.org/index.html#initialData=C4S2BsFMAIElkgW2gUQB6QMYFdgHsAnAKAAcBDA0TEcgO2GgGFwRJ7SKqaz7oAiVgC54SdFlyE+0MgGc4CRGJz5i5SiGp0GAhAWG6yKqbOhhIqzhu68++pAGVghyPfMA3DZGNyRiR89cCD0xIImZWegBaAD5wtmBBM0QZGLMCQ0IACgBKIjJMUDdnJhZ4sNKomLj6RN0AXiIAE0h8wuLq4CJwPDwSU10AOgALWQA5SDRgHOhyiOBU3UFaCancvIKQIoR+8yI0yKqKhKS65cmcppaNrZg02fiY3yUJPWgJ8QRMpNzWzeKnjDKQhELo9EhEAEfQjQGLyBxOBCBYKQRIyAD6SQxtDc8UIAE80XhaEM8OBGmiZAjIF8FAMQI0ftd-gp-Ij3J4Qb1Or5WS52SEDtFIUC9IJgARsKFmr8bnC-FSkRzhS8YUKFM8VIJoDIoJASJkSWToCRzCA8AyZjLmaJAS8IerbSpBcrNZcrdsXcC2I0iAAjAgtADWlqZHpZCv5oR5EaCnmdDqhooAZmRwDIpVc2mH4QFI0RvfnaD7PQRVSWtY08BS8IhIMAhiBaABzGlIRlZmAl+02xPxnsiwRu0OdhMi7uKR3QwUdQfS4dyjVeovQIA)

Some remarks on this diagram

- the `break-fragment` leaves the immediately enclosing fragment. Therefore it must be contained directly in the `loop-fragment`. If it is within an alt-fragment, only this fragment is left.
- Both `alt` and `opt` fragments don't use a `guard`. The fragment that happens is choosen by the occurrence of the `reply` message with a certain `return-value`. If you want to use a guard, you have to assign the return-value to a local variable. This would then happen above the alt-fragment (see diagram below).
- return values are shown with a preceeding colon. The message name would preceed this, but when it is obvious it can be omitted (as it is here).
- `execution specifications` (sometimes referred to as "activations") are only shown, where they help the readability. Contrary to popular belief they are not mandatory.
- UML doesn't know for each loops. Therefore I added iterator operations. The term "for each item in a list" is not a `guard` condition. If you want to avoid spelling out the iterator, you can use a - semantic free - `comment` attached to the loop. Misusing the boolean guard for this makes no sense. If you want a formal definition, you have to add you own stereotype `«for each loop»`
- I assume `ItemExecutor` and `ItemStateService` are class-names. They need a preceeding colon to distinguish them from role-names. Of course if the role- and class-names are identical, your diagram can be correct.
- The "Acknowledge" message is just the `reply` message for the `execute` message. As such it would carry the same name (which is omitted here).
- In the version with Execution Specifications, the drawing tool didn't allow the end of the `execution specifications` to coincide with the `send events` of the `reply-messages`, which would have been correct.

Example with guards for the `alt` and `break` fragments (excerpt):
[image: with guards]
[sequencediagram.org/Item Executor (with Execution Specifications and guards)](https://sequencediagram.org/index.html#initialData=C4S2BsFMAIElkgW2gUQB6QMYFdgHsAnAKAAcBDA0TEcgO2GgGFwRJ7SKqaz7oAiVgC54SdFlyE+0MgGc4CRGJz5i5SiGp0GAhAWG6yKqbOhhIqzhu68++pAGVghyPfMA3DZGNyRiR89cCD0xIImZWegBaAD5wtmBBMwJDQgAKAEoiMkxQN2cmFniwwqiYuPpE3QBeIgATSGzc-PLgInA8PBJTXQA6AAtZADlINGAM6GKI4BikwVoRscysnJA8hG7zIiTIspKEs0Qq+dGMuoaVtZgkyfiY3yUJPWgR8QRUg8zG1fz7jGVCIhtDokIi-V6EaAxeQOJwIQLBSCJGQAfQOqNobnihAAnsi8LQ+nhwLVkTJYZB3goeiBap8Lj8FP44e5PKDGeT4Z4dtEwf89CAUfjCcSavUvpdoX4OSyQoDOgwBXiCUTamzRH9HpCeQoHipBNAZFBICRUsLatASOYQHhaRNxQz1eDiLzHtyXXqzvb1u6AWxVQAjAgNADW0FoeAVguVxKI4fWeExBElusI+ugz0QJGA2OgADNkgBzRDxdOloh+8u0VU+pN3HUavXQWp4Ul4YvAPogWgFylIOlNb31p1qxQNwhuod8wSe+mDx18kcp2u7KbTsWzmA1yvmoA)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. You mean to say show an infinite loop with an explicit break condition and an optional sleep?

Comment: And where can I find these guidelines? Do you have some good reference article/book?

Comment: Well, not a (boolean) condition, but a break fragment, that occurs whenever the reply message comes back with a `false` return value. All these guidelines are directly from the specification, which is not really a good read as an introduction. I currently don't have a favorite book in English.

Comment: Well, that's not correct. The `break` will always be executed, so the loop will not be run at all.

Comment: And the `ExecutionSpecification` is missing for most parts too.

Comment: The `ExecutionSpecification` is optional. It adds two occurences to the traces, `start` and `finish` of the execution. That means it makes some traces invalid, that otherwise would not have been defined as valid or invalid. Since the whole universe of traces is much larger, this makes not much of a difference. Nevertheless, a useful style guideline could require to always include them.

Comment: The specification says "The semantics of an Interaction is given as a pair of sets of traces." The break fragment means, that one valid trace is `send reply, receive reply with return value false, next occurrence outside of the enclosing fragment`. It doesn't specify, that it must be executed. To specify this, an activity diagram could be used.

Comment: Indeed you are right with the citation. Nevertheless, I'd regard this a specification flaw. A break is "usually" used with loop control flows (plus a case control flow). So as a reader of your diagram I'd just be confused. It's probably the best to name the fragment so it's clear it will affect the outer loop fragment.

Comment: I agree, that the diagram looks confusing. Would it be better, if I used a guard with my break fragment? I added a version with guards. However, the confusion is sometimes a good thing, because it reminds people, what sequence diagrams actually specify.

Comment: @AxelScheithauer By adding guard to a break you mean "not is_onhold"?

Comment: @Lokesh, yes, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

A goto itself is not shown. You just show what operations are sent. You might add a note at the place where the goto happens. However, I think that the usage of gotos should not be encouraged in any way. Instead it should probably some exception handling.

According to your comments you can use a `break` fragment like this:

[image]

It will break the outer loop, so the `is_item...` is repeated after `sleep...`.

**Note** As per comment from @AxelScheithauer the `break` will just leave the enclosing fragment. However, I'd regard this a specification flaw. A break is "usually" used with loop control flows (plus a case control flow; but UML does not have a fragment for that). It's probably the best to name the `break` fragment so it's clear it will affect the outer loop fragment (as shown in my edited picture).

Comment: Thanks, can you please help me how this can be fixed for the example I mentioned in the question?

Comment: Actually I don't see any issue with your diagram except for the missing object activity parts (squares over life lines while there is activity). You should fix that issue. Also (most likely) the final Acknowledge is probably a return and not a message.

Comment: ya thanks for pointing the missing parts. I am just curious how can I show that once sleep time is elapsed I will again check "is_item_inventory_onhold_state"? Is note the best thing there and does it adheres to the general convention/rules?

Comment: So after the `sleep...` you want to continue at `ìs_item_...` above?

Comment: The specification says about the `break` operator: "the rest of the enclosing Interaction Fragment is ignored". Therefore, it will leave the `alt` fragment. It will not influence the loop.

Comment: You now gave the `break` the name "break outer loop". This doesn't change the semantics. Also the notation doesn't have a place for the name, so it would not be shown in the diagram. I suggest using a comment instead. This is also semantics free, but for a pragmatic model this is Ok, even though the correct place for user defined semantics would be a profile. However, why define irregular semantics, when the regular semantics cover the situation?

Comment: @AxelScheithauer I used that option from Enterprise Architect to name a fragment which adds the name after the keyword. Will check what the specs say about that.

Comment: `Fragment` is a `NamedElement`. I haven't found where to place the name, but right after the keyword seems logical. So I just assume that EA has implemented that correctly.

Comment: If you insist on your interpretation then you just **can not** use a `break` in correct programming logic (where you break a loop and not the enclosing `if` construct). However, I prefer common sense when dealing with languages (like UML which is one).

Comment: `break` as defined by UML is not a statement (as for example in Java). It is an operator of an InteractionFragment, that is used to define valid traces. A statement would be defined with an ActionExecutionSpecification. It's effect might then be visulized with the `break` fragment.

Comment: Not every name can be shown in a diagram. The specification says about the notation for CombinedFragments: _"The operator is shown in a pentagon in the upper left corner of the rectangle"_. Names are not mentioned.

Comment: @AxelScheithauer Ah, well. I won't lean out here. I think the notation is plausible. The specs DO have a couple of flaws. Again: for me common sense beats (questionable) specifications. UML is about communication. There's always more than one way to express things (noticing your added diagram I think that's a good interpretation).

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a 'goto', like we don't use them in language since long time

Add a second loop and go out with a combined fragment 'break'